# Splitting a string ignoring case in Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, split, series

What I need to do would be something like:

```py
df[col].str.split(my_regexp, re.IGNORECASE, expand=True)
```

However, the pandas `DataFrame.str.split` method doesn't have the possibility to add regexp flags.

Since I need to expand the results, I cannot do something like

```py
df.apply(lambda x: re.split(my_regexp, x[col], flags=re.IGNORECASE), axis=1, result='expand')
```

because the lists don't have the same length.

What I would need would be a way to either make `re.split`returns all lists of the same length, either pass the `re.IGNORECASE` in the `Series.str.split` method. Or maybe an even better way?

Thank you everyone!

Edit: Here is some data for a better explanation

```py
series = pd.Series([
    'First paRt foo second part FOO third part',
    'test1 FoO test2', 
    'hi1 bar HI2',
    'This is a Test',
    'first baR second BAr third',
    'final'
])
```

Should return with the regexp `r'foo|bar'`

```py
    0               1               2
0   First paRt      second part     third part
1   test1           test2           None
2   hi1             HI2             None
3   This is a Test  None            None
4   first           second          third
5   final           None            None
```

Comment: Could you add some example data, so we can try ourself and produce an answer for you?

Comment: Is it an option to write your `my_regexp` in lowercase and then use: `df[col].str.lower().str.split(my_regexp, expand=True)`

Comment: I added some examples. It would be a great idea but unfortunately I really need the strings to be identical in my output

Comment: Erfran solutions above lowers the case of the results too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Method 1: if lowercase / uppercase needs to be retained:

```
series.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(re.split(r'foo|bar', x, flags=re.IGNORECASE)))\
      .str.split(', ', expand=True)
```

**Output**

```
                0              1            2
0     First paRt    second part    third part
1          test1           test2         None
2            hi1             HI2         None
3  This is a Test           None         None
4          first         second         third
5           final           None         None
```

---

#### Method 2 if lowercase / uppercase is not an issue

As stated in the comments, broadcast your series to lowercase using `str.lower()` and then use `str.split`:

```
series.str.lower().str.split(r'foo|bar', expand=True)
```

**Output**

```
                0              1            2
0     first part    second part    third part
1          test1           test2         None
2            hi1             hi2         None
3  this is a test           None         None
4          first         second         third
5           final           None         None
```

---

#### Method 3 Removing the unnecessary whitespaces:

```
series.str.lower().str.split(r'foo|bar', expand=True).apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
```

**Output**

```
                0            1           2
0      first part  second part  third part
1           test1        test2        None
2             hi1          hi2        None
3  this is a test         None        None
4           first       second       third
5           final         None        None
```